# Element not found on page while scrolling down (StaleElementReferenceException)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently scrolling through a [TripAdivsor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g28970-d84078-Reviews-Hyatt_Regency_Washington_on_Capitol_Hill-Washington_DC_District_of_Columbia.html#/media/84078/?albumid=101&type=2&category=101) page to scrape images and need to scroll until the bottom of the page but keep getting the error of:

selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.

I am assuming it is because it is trying to go very fast through the page but even when I change the implicit wait time to be larger, it does not solve the issue. I also tried making sure the new location is visible first before parsing through to get the url but that also did not do any good. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
# import dependencies
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import re
import selenium
import io
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from _datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless=False

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/rishi/Downloads/chromedriver 3")
driver.maximize_window()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2} 
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

#open up website
driver.get(
    "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g28970-d84078-Reviews-Hyatt_Regency_Washington_on_Capitol_Hill-Washington_DC_District_of_Columbia.html#/media/84078/?albumid=101&type=2&category=101")


image_url = []

end = False
while not(end):
    #wait until element is found and then store all webelements into list
    images = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//*[@class="media-viewer-dt-root-GalleryImageWithOverlay__galleryImage--1Drp0"]')))

    #iterate through visible images and acquire their url based on background image style
    for index, image in enumerate(images):
        image_url.append(images[index].value_of_css_property("background-image"))

    #if you are at the end of the page then leave loop
    # if(length == end_length):
    #     end = True

    #move to next visible images in the array
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", images[-1])
    #time.sleep(1)
    #wait until the new web element is visible
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    #WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(images[-1]))

#clean the list to provide clear links
for i in range(len(image_url)):
    start = image_url[i].find("url(\"") + len("url(\"")
    end = image_url[i].find("\")")
    print(image_url[i][start:end])
```

Comment: what problem you are facing and in which element?

Comment: I am having trouble when just iterating through the whole pop up screen. As I collect everything that is visible, I scroll down to the last image added to the images list through images[-1]. The actual stopping points vary depending on the implicit wait time.